# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'OS_Mailinglist1' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#-2.0

Can anyone help me why I am getting this error? Thanks in advance..

> *Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
>   'OS_Mailinglist1' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
>   Exception Details:
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for
>   identity column in table 'OS_Mailinglist1' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set
>   to OFF.*
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 312: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>   Line 313: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert",
>   "alert('Successsfully Registered your Email ID and Area of
>   interest.');", true);

Code behind page that shows error:

```
else
{
        Util.SetConnection();
        Util.sql_con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into offsale.OS_Mailinglist1(UserName,Area_Of_Interest,Mail_Pwd)values('" + txtEmail.Text.ToString() + "' ,'" + arrvalues + "','" + ViewState["pwd"].ToString () + "')", Util.sql_con);
       // cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into offsale.OS_Mailinglist1(UserName,Area_of_interest,Mail_Pwd)values('" + txtEmail.Text.ToString() + "' ,'" + arrvalues + "','" + passwrd.Text.ToString () + "')", Util.sql_con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Successsfully Registered your Email ID and Area of interest.');", true);

      Util.sql_con.Close();
```

Comment: What does the DDL of the table in question (`OS_Mailinglist1`) look like?

Comment: You should **ALWAYS** use [**parametrized queries**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) and **not** concatenate together your SQL statements! That's opening the doors for SQL injection attacks, and it's detrimental to your SQL Server performance, too.

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to insert a value into an identity column. to explicitly allow this you have to to turn the global IDENTITY_INSERT session value on.